# Magento2 keeps loading without displaying the home page or the admin

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

My site keeps loading without displaying the home page or the admin.

---

var/log/debug.log:

```
main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"https://website.com/pct-eveil-tle-cde.html","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}} []
main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"GET","url":"http://website.com/robots.txt","invalidateInfo":{"identifier":"interception"}} []
```

pub/error_log:

```
PHP Deprecated:  Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing) should either be compatible with php_user_filter::filter($in, $out, &$consumed, bool $closing): int, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php on line 1107.

PHP Deprecated:  Return type of phpseclib_mcrypt_filter::onCreate() should either be compatible with php_user_filter::onCreate(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /vendor/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat/lib/mcrypt.php on line 1158
```

Answer (score 0):

Check php **mcrypt** module

Verify using below command

> php -m

If mcrypt module is listed, disable it from php8.1

Comment: mcrypt module is not listed

Comment: What is your PHP and Magento version ?

Comment: Sorry for delay, I use php 7.2 but I have upgrade to 8.1, still same

Comment: Create phpinfo.php in root dir. and write this code <?php phpinfo(); ?> in file. open in brower example.com/phpinfo.php.  and check memrory limit and mcrypt.

Comment: Fix it, but new problem again. https://prnt.sc/jI_QxpG3Dkc7

Comment: Please run indexer command  :-  php bin/magento indexer:reset  ..... then run ... php bin/magento indexer:reindex  ..... command

Comment: Thank yu Raj, but the issue persists. My Magento ver. is 2.3.1

Comment: https://www.hungersoft.com/info/display-new-products-on-magento-frontend